# Is $∀x((P(x)∨Q(x))) \to (∀x: (P(x) ∨ ∀x: Q(x)))$ correct.?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

The thing I'm trying to understand is why this problem is false?
[Isn't it the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a0ZN.png)?

Comment: 1) for all n, n is even or n is odd. 2) for all n n is even, or for all n, n is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The antecedent (the thing before the arrow) says everything is either $P$ or $Q$, the consequent (thing after the arrow) says either everything is $P$, or everything is $Q$. The former does not imply the latter. For instance, it could be that there are two things, one of which is $P$ and another is $Q$, but no thing is both $P$ and $Q$. In this case the antecedent is true, but the consequent is false while the antecedent is true.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you like my answer, you can accept it :)